# Soundcloud Minimal Page Oversize

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, mobile, soundcloud

i'm currently in middle of developing a mobile app/site and i'm using the jquery mobile framework and also the SC Minimal custom player found here:

https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-custom-player/blob/master/examples/sc-player-minimal.html

The custom player plays fine, that's not the issue, the issue i'm seem to be getting is that the page it is on seems to change the main body into some sort of iframe with a added scroller on the right side of the screen. This is a example page

http://www.blackburnravers.com/test/media/blackburnravers/blackburnravers_hypedup.html

I also have the latest jquery installed on my server, i just can't seem to find anything conflicting anywhere

Here's the code i'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Blackburn Ravers - Hyped Up Mix</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/themes/blackburnravers.mob-3.0.0.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../_assets/css/jqm-brctemplates.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,700&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="../../js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../../_assets/js/index.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js"></script>
    <script src="//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/soundcloud.player.api.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/sc-player.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/sc-player-minimal.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" class="jqm-brctemplates" data-quicklinks="true">

    <div data-role="header" class="jqm-header">
        <h1 class="jqm-logo"><a href="#wedowhatwewant" data-transition="flip" data-inline="true" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window"><img src="../../_assets/img/blackburnravers-logo.png" alt="The Blackburn Ravers - DJ NJ & Dj Upalnite"></a></h1>

        <div data-role="popup" id="wedowhatwewant" data-overlay-theme="f" data-theme="f" data-tolerance="15,15" class="ui-content">
            <div data-role="content" data-theme="f">
                <center>
                    WE DO WHAT WE WANT!
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>

        <a href="#" class="jqm-navmenu-link" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Navigation</a>
        <a href="#" class="jqm-search-link" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="notext">Search</a>

        <div class="jqm-search">
            <ul class="jqm-list">

            </ul>
        </div>

    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" class="jqm-content">

        <h1>Hyped Up Mix</h1>

        <p>
            Re-recording of our set from Hyped up from Friday 14/06/2013.<br />
            Fantastic night and superb bunch down there.
            <p>
                <a href="https://soundcloud.com/blackburnravers/hypedupmix" class="sc-player">Hyped Up Mix</a>
            </p>        
            <br />
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="c">
            <h4>Tracklist</h4>
                    <ol data-role="listview">
                        <li>Scott Brown - All About Elysium (Al Storm Remix)</li>
                        <li>Darren Styles & Squad-E - Party People</li>
                        <li>Asa & S1 Feat. Lou Lou - Makin� Me Wanna Dance (Sy & Unknown Remix)</li>
                        <li>Ben Xtreme & Mc Ortie - Looking Down (Dj Kurt Remix)</li>
                        <li>Darren Styles - Take Me Away</li>
                        <li>Darren Styles - Save Me (Re-Con Remix)</li>
                        <li>Dougal & Gammer Feat. Lisa Abott - Something Good</li>
                        <li>Gusto - Discos Revenge (Breeze's Filthy Hardcore Mix)</li>
                        <li>Joey Riot & Chaos - I Wanna Freak U Bby</li>
                        <li>Paradise - Angel (Sy & Unknown Remix)</li>
                        <li>Re-Con Feat. Sophie may - Dont hold calling back (Azzyd Vox Booty)</li>
                        <li>Anon - How Low (Naughty is Nice Remix)</li>
                        <li>Scott Brown - Rock You Softly (UFO & Supreme Remix)</li>
                        <li>Dj Kurt - Right About Now</li>
                        <li>Starkillers - Discoteka (Dougal & Gammer Remix)</li>
                    </ol>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="ui-grid-a">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <center><a href="#screenshot" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-theme="b" data-inline="true" data-transition="fade"><img width="150px" src="img_covers/blackburnravers_hypedup_disc.png" alt="Hyped Up Mix"></a></center>
                    <div data-role="popup" id="screenshot" class="photopopup" data-overlay-theme="a" data-corners="false" data-tolerance="30,15" >
                        <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a><img src="img_covers/blackburnravers_hypedup_disc.png" alt="Hyped Up Mix">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <center><a href="#screenshot2" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-theme="b" data-inline="true" data-transition="fade"><img width="150px" src="img_covers/blackburnravers_hypedup_back.png" alt="Hyped Up Mix"></a></center>
                    <div data-role="popup" id="screenshot2" class="photopopup" data-overlay-theme="a" data-corners="false" data-tolerance="30,15" >
                        <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a><img src="img_covers/blackburnravers_hypedup_back.png" alt="Hyped Up Mix">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /grid-b -->
            <br />
            <div class="ui-grid-a">
                <div class="ui-block-a"><a href='https://soundcloud.com/blackburnravers/hypedupmix' data-role="button" data-theme="g">SoundCloud</a></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#share-panel" data-role="button" data-theme="a">Share</a></div>
            </div><!-- /grid-b -->
        </p>


    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" class="jqm-footer">
        <p><span class="copyright">&copy;</span> 2013 The Blackburn Ravers - 
            <a href="#aboutapp" data-transition="fade" data-inline="true" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">DJ NJ & Dj Upalnite</a>
            <div data-role="popup" id="aboutapp" data-overlay-theme="f" data-theme="f" data-tolerance="15,15" class="ui-content">
                <div data-role="content" data-theme="f">
                    <center><img src="../../_assets/img/blackburnravers-logo.png" alt="The Blackburn Ravers - DJ NJ & Dj Upalnite"></center>
                    <br />
                    App Version - <i>v3.0.0</i><br />
                    App Creator - <i>Dj Upalnite</i><br />
                    Bugs - <a href="mailto:blackburnravers@gmail.com"><i>Please email us</i></a><br />
                    Website - <a href="http://www.blackburnravers.com" target="_blank"><i>www.blackburnravers.com</i></a><br /><br />
                </div>
            </div>
        </p>
    </div><!-- /footer -->

    <!-- Here are a bunch of panels at the end, just before the close page tag  -->

    <!-- main navigation panel -->
    <div data-role="panel" class="jqm-nav-panel jqm-navmenu-panel" data-position="left" data-display="reveal" data-theme="a">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a" data-divider-theme="f" data-icon="false" class="jqm-list">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Main Links</li>
            <li data-filtertext="Home" data-ajax="false"><a href="../../">Home</a></li>
            <li data-filtertext="Media" data-ajax="false"><a href="../../media/">Mixes</a></li>
            <li data-filtertext="ajax navigation navigate event method"><a href="../../socialnetworks/">Social Sites</a></li>
            <li data-filtertext="ajax navigation navigate event method"><a data-ajax="false" href="../../events/">Events</a></li>
            <li data-filtertext="ajax navigation navigate event method"><a href="../../contactus/">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li data-filtertext="ajax navigation navigate event method"><a href="http://www.blackburnravers.com/">Main Website</a></li>

            <li data-role="list-divider">Mix Section</li>
            <li data-filtertext="ajax navigation navigate event method"><a href="./">Blackburn Ravers</a></li>
            <li data-filtertext="ajax navigation navigate event method"><a href="../djupalnite/">Dj Upalnite</a></li>
            <li data-filtertext="ajax navigation navigate event method"><a href="../djnj/">DJ NJ</a></li>
            <li data-filtertext="ajax navigation navigate event method"><a href="../madforit/">Mad For It</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /main navigation panel -->

    <div data-role="panel" id="share-panel" data-display="reveal" data-position="right" data-theme="a">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a" data-divider-theme="f" data-icon="false" class="jqm-list">

            <li data-role="list-divider">Share this page</li>
            <li><a href="http://twitter.com/share?text=Hyped%20Up%20Mix&url=https://soundcloud.com/blackburnravers/hypedupmix" onclick="window.open('http://twitter.com/share?text=Hyped%20Up%20Mix&url=https://soundcloud.com/blackburnravers/hypedupmix','twittershare','width=450,height=300,left='+(screen.availWidth/2-225)+',top='+(screen.availHeight/2-150)+'');return false;">Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://soundcloud.com/blackburnravers/hypedupmix" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://soundcloud.com/blackburnravers/hypedupmix','facebookshare','width=450,height=300,left='+(screen.availWidth/2-225)+',top='+(screen.availHeight/2-150)+'');return false;">Facebook</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://m.google.com/app/plus/x/?v=compose&content=https://soundcloud.com/blackburnravers/hypedupmix" onclick="window.open('https://m.google.com/app/plus/x/?v=compose&content=https://soundcloud.com/blackburnravers/hypedupmix','gplusshare','width=450,height=300,left='+(screen.availWidth/2-225)+',top='+(screen.availHeight/2-150)+'');return false;">Google +</a></li>
            <li><a href="mailto:?subject=I wanted you to listen to this mix&amp;body=Check out this mix https://soundcloud.com/blackburnravers/hypedupmix" title="Share by Email" onclick="window.open('mailto:?subject=I wanted you to listen to this mix&amp;body=Check out this mix https://soundcloud.com/blackburnravers/hypedupmix','email','width=450,height=300,left='+(screen.availWidth/2-225)+',top='+(screen.availHeight/2-150)+'');return false;">Email</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /panel -->

</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

is there something i could have missed? hope somebody can help me,

thanks,

Blackburn Ravers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. For some reason there was 2 'content' classes that where clashing and causing it to over scale and resize the page. I removed it from my code and it is working perfect.

thank you for your time looking at it for me.  Cheers.
Blackburn Ravers.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at it and then refreshed the page and it seems that the code changed so I am figuring that you are playing with it. I'm not sure but before the change, I believe that it seemed like .sc.scrubber div was the issue. Try using max-width: 100% (or 95% I believe was in there) instead of just width: 100%.

Comment: no worries pal, i'll give it a go now, yeah sorry i was messing around with some code.

Comment: right i've tried adding that to my css file but i'm getting no results yet, it just seems to keep doing the same. I've set up a new demo page which is here: http://www.blackburnravers.com/test/ddddd.html